# trying to create a gridview in vb.net and every time a new row is overwritten on the first row help me with this code plz

Tags: vb.net

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        dt.Columns.Add("LR No")
        dt.Columns.Add("Description")
        dt.Columns.Add("Article")
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity")
        dt.Columns.Add("Net Weight")
        dt.Columns.Add("Gross Weight")
        dt.Columns.Add("Freight")
        dt.Columns.Add("Remark")
        GridLRData.DataSource = dt
    End Sub

    Protected Sub BtnAddLRData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAddLRData.Click
  
        dt.Rows.Add(TxtLRNo.Text, TxtDescription.Text, DlArticle.Text, TxtQuantity.Text, TxtNetWeight.Text, TxtGrossWeight.Text, TxtFreight.Text, TxtRemark.Text)

        GridLRData.DataSource = dt

        GridLRData.DataBind()

        TxtDescription.Text = ""
        DlArticle.Text = ""
        TxtQuantity.Text = ""
        TxtNetWeight.Text = ""
        TxtGrossWeight.Text = ""
        TxtFreight.Text = ""
        TxtRemark.Text = ""


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution below works correctly!

```
Public Class Form1
        Private dt As DataTable
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            dt = New DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add("LR No")
            dt.Columns.Add("Description")
            dt.Columns.Add("Article")
            dt.Columns.Add("Quantity")
            dt.Columns.Add("Net Weight")
            dt.Columns.Add("Gross Weight")
            dt.Columns.Add("Freight")
            dt.Columns.Add("Remark")
            GridLRData.DataSource = dt
        End Sub
    
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            dt.Rows.Add(TxtLRNo.Text, TxtDescription.Text, DlArticle.Text, TxtQuantity.Text, TxtNetWeight.Text, TxtGrossWeight.Text, TxtFreight.Text, TxtRemark.Text)
    
                  
            GridLRData.Refresh()
    
            TxtDescription.Text = ""
            DlArticle.Text = ""
            TxtQuantity.Text = ""
            TxtNetWeight.Text = ""
            TxtGrossWeight.Text = ""
            TxtFreight.Text = ""
            TxtRemark.Text = ""
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: i m getting an error 'Refresh' is not a member of System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView

Comment: This solution was for a WinForm application. Sorry!

Comment: any other solutions to this problem